# Restore scrollbar arrows (or their functionality)

Tags: macos

For workflow purposes, I still use a 2003 eMac running Leopard a decent amount of time, and really miss some of its features in the newer, less civilized downgrades of the operating system. In particular, the scroll bars by the side of the window (which one can force the OS to display, albeit far smaller than they used to be) used to have arrow icons to move up on down one screen. If one were really determined, [this preferences setting](https://lifehacker.com/5040043/add-double-scroll-arrows-to-both-ends-of-the-scroll-bar) allowed the arrows to appear both above *and* below the scroll bar.

In the newer OS versions that newer hardware is stuck with (say, anything that doesn't have a large cat name), is there any way (preferences setting, AppleScript, helper app, etc) to bring back the arrow icons to scroll up and down precisely one screen per click or, failing that, to bring back their functionality easily from the mouse/trackpad? Page Up/Down isn't really a solution, as it takes both hands.

Comment: One screen per click can be done with the spacebar, so long as you're not in a text area, or truly mouse-driven, something like [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) can do all that kind of thing.

Comment: Spacebar works for going down, but not up, and not in text areas – and it still requires moving to the keyboard, not the mouse/trackpad.

Comment: Then maybe something like steermouse; the more buttons you have the more options you have. I used it for years on an old MX-518 until its sad demise, barely touched the keyboard unless I was typing. I now have an MX Master & am forced to use the Logitec control, nowhere near as good.